# Unable to import wave (EOFError)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't really figure out what went wrong. Could you please tell me what might be the problem? Thanks!

Below is the error info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
   File "demo.py", line 17, in <module>
    import wave
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 259
    raise EOFError from None
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: this is really strange, how did you install python? the version is 3.8? If you execute the line `raise EOFError from None` in a new terminal does it raise a `SyntaxError`?